# Is there a way to connect Airbyte helm chart to an external temporal?

Tags: airbyte

I reviewed the values of Airbyte helm chart managed to connect it to an external S3 and postgres database, but I want now to customised temporal

the temporal section in the helm chart values has no properties to add an external cluster IP

I was thinking of something similar to MINIO

```
externalTemporal::
  # -- Enable or disable an external Temporal instance
  enabled: false
  # -- External Temporal host
  host: localhost
  # -- External Temporal port
  port: 9000
```